# onTapGesure not registering for background of ScrollView

Tags: swift, swiftui, scrollview, swiftui-ontapgesture

For some reason, the `.onTapGesture` event won't fire for the background of the ScrollView, but it does fire correctly when applied to the background of a nested VStack view:

```
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView {
            VStack {...}
            .background(
                Rectangle()
                    .fill(.red)
                    .onTapGesture {
                        print("!!!CLICKED!!!")
                    }
            )
        }
        .background(
            Rectangle()
                .fill(.green)
                .onTapGesture {
                    print("!!!CLICKED!!!")
                }
        )
    }
```

So when I click the red area, I'm able to see "!!!CLICKED!!!" printed, but when I click the green area, nothing is printed:

[ViewLayout image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oxV7y.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To trigger the action on the background of the `ScrollView`, just move the `.onTapGesture()` modifier to the bottom of the `ScrollView` itself, instead of the `.background()`.

Here below, you will see a sample code that works (I added a couple of variables to notice the effect directly on the screen):

```
@State private var clicked = "Nothing"  // For testing purposes only
@State private var alternate = true     // For testing purposes only
    
var body: some View {
    ScrollView {
        VStack {
            Text("One")
            Text("Two")
            Text("Three")
            
            Text(clicked)  // For testing purposes: see what was clicked on the screen
                .padding()
            Text(alternate ? "Clicked" : "... and again")  // See the effect after each click
        }
        .background(
            Rectangle()
                .fill(.red)
                .onTapGesture {
                    clicked = "Clicked red"
                    alternate.toggle()
                    print("!!!CLICKED RED!!!")
                }
        )
    }
    
    // Here is where the modifier should be to trigger the action on the background of the ScrollView
    .onTapGesture {
        clicked = "Clicked green"
        alternate.toggle()
        print("!!!CLICKED GREEN!!!")
    }
    .background(
        Rectangle()
            .fill(.green)
    )
}
```

Comment: Awesome! Can't believe I didn't think of that. Works like a charm, thanks @HunterLion!